# launch and submit job spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I try to "run" spark jobs width my java application, searching, I found the following two methods:
`ClientsArguments` and `SparkLauncher`.

Could someone explain to me the difference between the two? The difference between launch and submit job/application Spark?
Thank you.

Comment: I read the documentation, but I can not quite understand the difference !!

Comment: Ehm, have you looked at `spark-submit`??

Comment: You can not answer the question, simply?
I'm afraid I do not understand the subtlety between the two, it's just to prove or disprove my intuition!

Answer (score 1):

SparkLauncher is just a wrapper library for `spark-submit`, it coverts your `SparkLauncher` code to `spark-submit` **script** and then trigger the jobs.

The mechanism is the same with `spark-submit` script, if you look at the source code of SparkLauncher, it uses `ProcessBuilder` to construct the shell.

If you want to use `SparkLauncher`, you need to specify `$JAVA_HOME`, `$SPRAK_HOME` and other essential parameters. There are some limitation for `SparkLauncher`, the machine your `SparkLauncher` runs must have a `$JAVA_HOME` and `$SPARK_HOME`(Spark Library) which is used for `SparkLauncher` locating the **script** and related dependencies. This is soft of impossible for some cloud environment like CloudFoundry etc.

You could assume that `SparkLauncher` equals `spark-submit` script, you could choose client or master, local or yarn mode.

`ClientsArguments` is a class for YARN script, which is only works for yarn-mode.